# When do I install mud-rings?

Tags: electrical, drywall, junction-box

Following the advice I've received here, I'm doing all my new-work wiring in deep, 4" square, metal boxes, and I'll be placing single- or double-gang mud rings on them for mounting devices.

I would presume that I should install the mud-rings *before* installing the drywall, then cut out the drywall to the appropriate exposed gang size.

However, I got to thinking (as I sometimes do) that this means that the screws that hold the mud ring in place are semi-permanently buried beneath drywall and, if I should ever need to go from a single- to double-gang at this location I'd be doing drywall repair work. To avoid this issue, I could install the drywall then cut it around the 4" box, *but* that would probably leave me with a  hole in the drywall larger than even a jumbo size wall plate would cover, especially if it's a single-gang.

Am I correct in my presumption that I am to install the mud-rings and bury their mounting screws under the drywall?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the mudrings go on before the drywall.  Going from single to double is far less of a problem than vise-versa. The drywall you cut out to change from single to double gang will be covered by the new double cover, unless you cut far too much.